# Stored procedure to Insert Record Keeping Display Order

Tags: sql-server

Hello I have an application that works but the performance is slow on a row insert after rows in table are above 700.  I know a stored procedure would work better but am very new to creating them and need some help.

In the grid I provide the user an option to insert a row anywhere they want to.  I prompt them for the **TASK_ID** (displayOrder) that they want the new insert to be then in the app I renumber all the task_id's below the insert(**TASK_ID**) to "make room" for the new insert so that the new insert will be in the correct order when the grid refreshes.

How can I accomplish this insert via an SP?

```
Table structure 
ID(PK)(int),TASK_ID(displayOrder)(int),project_id(INT), otherColumns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of a stored procedure is that you can run batches of operations so logically connected changes can all occur in the context of a single transaction.

In your case you should write a procedure to accept all the parameters you need. Next, run an UPDATE something like

UPDATE [Table] SET Task_ID = Task_ID+1 WHERE Task_ID<@DesiredTaskId

after which you can run your insert.